# Customizing Joomla PDF output

Tags: pdf, joomla

In Joomla 1.5 constructor of `JDocumentPDF` class has an array parameter to setup some parameter of generated PDF.

```
function __construct($options = array()) {
    parent::__construct($options);

    if (isset($options['margin-header'])) {
        $this->_margin_header = $options['margin-header'];
    }

    if (isset($options['margin-footer'])) {
        $this->_margin_footer = $options['margin-footer'];
    }

    if (isset($options['margin-top'])) {
        $this->_margin_top = $options['margin-top'];
    }
    ...
}
```

`_createDocument()` function of `JFactory` class instantiates `JDocumentPDF` object, but doesn't pass any options that useful for PDF generation:

```
function &_createDocument()     {

    ...

    $attributes = array (
        'charset'   => 'utf-8',
        'lineend'   => 'unix',
        'tab'       => '  ',
        'language'  => $lang->getTag(),
        'direction' => $lang->isRTL() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'
    );

    $doc =& JDocument::getInstance($type, $attributes);
    return $doc;
}
```

So I don't understand how it works and where can I set this options (`margin-header`, `margin-footer` etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To `set` and `get` any properties of `JDocumentPDF`

you can call set and get function on `object`. For example

```
$obj = JFactory::getDocument();
$marginHeader  = $obj->get('_margin_header');
$obj->set('_margin_header', $value);
```

Comment: get and set will work with ll object of joomla classes, which are inherited by JObject.

Comment: Thanks, it works! BTW, based on your solution it can be solved with php magic methods.

Comment: but JDocument class is defined by Joomla. In this case you need to extend it, or need to make change in core code. If all this thing is available in Joomla, why should we prefer hacking code.